# Get rotation from Tiled object

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

How can I get rotation from Tiled map object?

It's listed in the properties, but `object.getProperties().get("rotation");` returns null and so does this: `object.getProperties().get("Rotation");`.

My first though was to cast the whole object into Rectangle object, but Rectangle doesn't keep rotation.

Comment: try https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=787

Comment: I've come across this post and the problem is, that I don't use tiles, I am using object and therefore, I can't get any texture from which I would get the rotation.

Comment: LibGDX supports features in the release version of Tiled. Object rotation is not yet included in that feature set.